# 2D - Firepoint not rotating consistently to aim at mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Followed brackeys tutorial for topdown shooter firing and although its working e.g the firepoint is rotating so it points towards the mouse its not happening consistently meaning it will stay pointed at a single spot for a few seconds before jumping towards the new spot. This delay before jumping to the new spot seems to be increased if i fire. Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a basic mistake as im new to C#

This is the Code i'm using to aim the firepoint.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FirepointAim : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public Camera cam;

Vector2 mousePos;

// Update is called once per frame 8
void Update(){
  mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}

void FixedUpdate(){
  Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
  float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;
  rb.rotation = angle;
}
```

}

And this is the code im using to fire.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform firepoint;
public GameObject fireballPrefab;
public Rigidbody2D playerrb;

public float velocity = 20f;
public float push = 2f;

void Update(){
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        shoot();
    }
}

void shoot()
{
  GameObject shot = Instantiate(fireballPrefab, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
  Rigidbody2D rb = shot.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
  rb.AddForce(firepoint.up * velocity, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
  playerrb.AddForce(firepoint.up * push * -1, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this by copying those scripts exactly without any change, and it rotates just smoothly. Can you try to put some debug output on mouse-movement? For example with `UnityEngine.Debug.Log("pos="+mousePos.ToString());`

Comment: If getting jerky stalls, the reason can also be some other scripts throwing a bunch of exception. Make sure the console is clean and remains free of any messages when testing. Also check Analysis->Profiler if you have some frames taking excessive amount of time due to whatever script hanging in loops forever.